# Changing from theme-cloudy to theme-default in apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an application, where the theme is set to  cloudy.Now i want  to change  the theme from cloudy  to standard .

Is it possible to change the existing theme .If so,could you please let me know the steps.

Comment: To which theme, theme 42 Universal theme?

Comment: Yes pars,in version 4.2.Do you have any idea?

Comment: but Theme 42 is not in Apex 4.2, if you want to switch to another theme number then specify which theme no. because there are 6 standard theme sin apex 4.2 from theme 21 to theme 26.

Comment: yup sorry,it's theme 21

Comment: look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35125/ui_themes.htm#HTMDB26005 for switch theme